# Magento 2: Observer event on cart page

Tags: cart, magento2.2

Please let me know which event observer is to be used when user is redirected to `view cart` in `magento 2.2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below event for **checkout/cart/index** action.

```
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index
```

Comment: hi @dinesh, is there any event for search result page?

Comment: hi @Dinesh this is not working